# How to find average by row based on the one column using sql

Tags: sql

hope you are well.

| Resource | Reason | Qty | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Broken | 15 | 48% |
| 11 | Shifted | 5 | 16% |
| 11 | Flash | 10 | 32% |
| 11 | Bleed | 1 | 3% |

So as you can see in the table above, I have a resource that has scrap and we need to break each reason down by % of the total.

So as you can see there is a total 31 scraps and I want to break each scrap by % for a particular Resource. I am not sure how to break it down by %

How would I be able the % in this way using SQL?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions.  To get the ratios:

```
select t.*,
       (t.qty * 1.0 / sum(t.qty) over (partition by resource)) as ratio
from t;
```

You can multiply by 100 if you want a percentage between 0 and 100 rather than a ratio.

Comment: What is t? I am sorry but I am pretty new at this

Comment: @Gordon Lindoff meant to say that replace 1 by 100 to get the Average field you want.